# Select Box Selected Item Staying After Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu, html-table

I currently have a table sorted by several select boxes. The select boxes work correctly and sort/filter the table, but whenever the user submits the search, the page refreshes and the select box resets. I would like the selected item to stick after a search, so for example if you select Male then hit go, after the page refreshes, Male is still selected. I currently have infinite scrolling successfully implemented, and I am using rails 3 and twitter-bootstrap for my framework if that helps any.

Here is my code:

**index.html.erb**

```
 <form class="form-inline"
        <p>
         <label class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="gender_search" value="M">M
         </label>
        <label class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="gender_search" value="F">F
        </label>

        <select name="state_search" class="span2">
          <option value="">Select a State</option>
          <option>----------------</option>
          <option>LA</option>
          <option>MS</option>
          <option>TX</option>
        </select>
        <select name="city_search" class="span2">
          <option value="">Select a City</option>
          <option>----------------</option>
          <option>Mandeville</option>
          <option>Covington</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">GO</button>
        </p>
      </form>
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered span8 table-condensed"     
       id="articles_table" >
        <thead class="header">
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Created_At</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <%= render @articles %>
        </tbody>
```

**_article.html.erb**

```
<tr>
      <td> <%= article_counter +1 %> </td>
      <td> <%= article.Title %> </td>
      <td> <%= article.Description %> </td>
      <td> <%= article.Created_At %> </td>
</tr>
```

**articles_controller.rb**

```
def index
@articles = Article.state_search(params[:state_search]).gender_search(params[:gender_search]).city_search(params[:city_search]).page(params[:page]).limit(50).order('NTRP DESC', 'Last_Name ASC')
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @articles }
    format.js
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well,

```
select_tag(:city_id, options_for_select([['Lisbon', 1], ['Madrid', 2]], @previous_choice)
```

First, I recommend you use Rails's form helpers to make things neater! your form would look like:

```
<%= form_tag articles_path, :method => "GET" do %>

    <%= radio_button_tag :gender_search, "M" %>
    <%= label_tag :gender_search_M, "M" %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :gender_search, "F" %>
    <%= label_tag :gender_search_F, "F" %>

    <%= select_tag :state_search, options_for_select([['Select a state', 0],['-----------', 0],['LA', 'LA'],['MS', 'MS'], ['TX', 'TX']], @prev_state) %>
    <%= select_tag :city_search, mptions_for_select([['Select a city', 0],['----------', 0],['Mandeville', 'Mandeville'],['Covington', 'Covington']], @prev_city) %>

    <%= submit_tag "Go" %>

<% end %>
```

Notice @prev_state and @prev_city in select_tag . These are set in articles_controller:

```
def index

    @prev_city = params[:city_search]
    @prev_state = params[:state_search]

    # other stuff
end
```

so the idea is everytime the user submits, params[:xxx] contains whatever she selected. Then, you make variables that are available in the view, with which we feed to options_for_select.

Hope this helps, happy railing!

Comment: This creates the select box that sorts the table correctly, but it does not stick after I hit go. I can post my code if it is needed. @Xiao

Comment: i'm looking into it! will answer later

Comment: Thanks but the other answer worked for me! Your answer would still be helpful though because its always good to know more than one way to do something! @Xiao

Comment: you're on the money, there is always more stuff to learn fortunately and unfortunately. Take a peek at my edits above, I've tested the form and it looks solid. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! I like this answer much better than the other one! I recently posted another question related to the radio buttons with the same concept. Can you take a look at it if you get a chance? Thanks again! @Xiao